# Can I safely move a Composer-created Laravel project to another directory?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I accidently installed my Laravel project in `user/name` via Composer, instead of the `htdocs` folder.

1. Can I just copy/paste the project to the `htdocs` folder?
2. Or should I uninstall the project first and then make a new app again via Composer?

Comment: You wouldn't normally put a Laravel project in your web root directory, because Laravel's /public folder should be the web root for the project

Comment: Um, yeah, perhaps I could make a new web root access directly to that folder :( but, can I just copy paste it to another directory ? :( I'm afraid the plugins or something can't be called because I change my directory :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, projects created with Composer are **self-contained** and are **not dependent on it's location on the file system** (I'm not familiar with Laravel in special, but I do not have any reason to suspect different behaviour here). You can move/copy them around without problems.

Concerning your worries about plugins not being loadable after moving the directory: Have a look at how Composer generates it's autoloader classmaps (below just a short excerpt):

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'File_Iterator' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Iterator.php',
    'File_Iterator_Facade' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Facade.php',
    'File_Iterator_Factory' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Factory.php',
    'PHPUnit_Exception' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/phpunit/src/Exception.php',
    // ...
```

As you can see, the autoloader is not wired against any fixed file system paths, so even the classloader files that are auto-generated by Composer can easily be moved around in the file system.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detail and simple for me to understand answer ! I understand it now thnx :)

Answer (score 3):

I did move mine and it accidentally broke, couldn't access any data via endpoints. **To fix it**, in the new project;

1. Make sure all files from the previous project folder are copied to the new folder. Especially the `.env` file.
2. In the new folder, run `composer install` in the terminal.
3. Then run `php artisan key:generate` to generate a new key in the `.env` file of the new folder.

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned make sure to move all files including hidden files (eg: .env)

I had to clear my config caches:

```
 php artisan config:cache
```

And to be safe clear the other caches

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```